# Humhub registration error

Tags: php, mysql, yii, open-basedir

I've installed [humhub](https://www.humhub.org/) on a shared webhoster. When I try to register as a new user the following error appears:

```
PHP Warning:
is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/.sites/26/site2378/web:/home/.sites/26/site2378/tmp:/usr/share/pear)
```

I have no access to files outside the htaccess folder.
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

There is already a discussion on github about that topic, however it doesn't help me much.
https://github.com/humhub/humhub/issues/129#issuecomment-60216954

Thanks for your answers

Comment: chmod/chown of files/directories are set? Meaby limitations of Your web provider.

Comment: simply email your hosting provider to remove the restriction

Comment: I'm gonna try it!
Thank you for your quick answers